# Getting error by moving code in function body - Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, arrays

I'm studying php and now i want to simplify my code using function, for some reason i got an error -  Invalid argument supplied for foreach(). And i can't figure out why, because my code worked just fine before i move it in function body, there is it:

```
$leftMenu = array(
    array('link'=>'Домой', 'href'=>'index.php'),
    array('link'=>'О нас', 'href'=>'about.php'),
    array('link'=>'Контакты', 'href'=>'contact.php'),
    array('link'=>'Таблицы умножения', 'href'=>'table.php'),
    array('link'=>'Калькулятор', 'href'=>'calc.php')    
);

function drawMenu ($leftMenu, $vertical = true){
    '<ul>';
    foreach ($leftMenu as $value){
        echo('<li><a href="'.$value['href'].'">'.$value['link'].'</a></li>');   
    }
    '</ul>';
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks! I also want to notice that code above WORK, but it did print error.

Comment: Missing Echo on the UL Tags

Comment: How are you calling drawMenu

Comment: pass in the $leftMenu as an argument,  drawMenu ($leftMenu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see some mistakes in your code since you are not printing any `<ul>`. For the correct use of the function you need to pass the data, in your case the `$leftMenu` array

```
function drawMenu ($leftMenu, $vertical = true)
{
   echo '<ul>';
   foreach ($leftMenu as $value)
   {
       echo '<li><a href="'.$value['href'].'">'.$value['link'].'</a></li>';   
   }
   echo '</ul>';
}
```

Now call the function

```
drawMenu($leftMenu);
```

This should print your list.  As side note i noticed you place second parameter in your function `$vertical = true` but you didn't use actually.

Comment: Vertical i want to use later, thanks you for notice.

Comment: I modified code like you told me, but it still warning on this line, containing foreach declaration.

Comment: you need first to declare the function, then declare the array and finally to call the function, did you do that in this order?

Comment: I found the problem thanks. I called function like this - drawMenu (0,0), i wonder why program point at line 41 which contain function declaration, not line when i call it wrong!

Comment: are you including/requiring any file? if so the number of line are changed arrcoding to what is added

Comment: No, I'm not. Still thank you again for solving my problem Fabio

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
$leftMenu = array(
    array('link'=>'Домой', 'href'=>'index.php'),
    array('link'=>'О нас', 'href'=>'about.php'),
    array('link'=>'Контакты', 'href'=>'contact.php'),
    array('link'=>'Таблицы умножения', 'href'=>'table.php'),
    array('link'=>'Калькулятор', 'href'=>'calc.php')    
);

function drawMenu ($leftMenu, $vertical = true) {
    $menu = '<ul>';
    foreach ($leftMenu as $value) {
        $menu .= ('<li><a href="'.$value['href'].'">'.$value['link'].'</a></li>');   
    }
    $menu .= '</ul>';

    return $menu;
} 

echo drawMenu($leftMenu);

?>
```